# How can I position my content next to my sidebar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I am not very well versed in HTML and CSS. I am currently building a website and I integrated a sidebar into my web application using [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29), but it has messed up my layouts, and I can't seem to figure out how to move the content in a block to the left of side of my sidebar.

Please view the image on this link.
As seen in the picture above, my sidebar is located at the right and my content is located at the below of my sidebar. Below are my codes for my sidebar and the base template.

```js
// Not bringing sidebar when active
const menu_toggle = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');

// When the button is clicked the sidebar will be active in the following code
menu_toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menu_toggle.classList.toggle('is-active');
  sidebar.classList.toggle('is-active');
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Sidebar Section */

.app {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(#ed7014, #fa5b3d);
  /* With Scrollbar */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}

.sidebar h3 {
  font-family: 'Bungee', cursive;
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar .menu {
  margin: 0 -1rem;
}

.sidebar .menu .menu-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.sidebar .menu .menu-item:hover,
.sidebar .menu .menu-item.is-active {
  color: rgb(255, 238, 151);
  ;
  border-right: 5px solid rgb(255, 238, 151);
}


/* Content Scrollbar */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffa500;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #d67229;
}


/* Content Section */

.content {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: linear-gradient(#dd5713, #d67229);
}

.content img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.content h1 {
  font-family: 'Bungee', cursive;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.content strong {
  font-family: 'Bungee', cursive;
  color: #fff;
}

.content p {
  text-align: justify;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Sample Code Content */

.sample-code {
  width: 65%;
  background: rgb(255, 238, 151);
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px;
}

.sample-code p {
  color: #000;
}


/* Button Sidebar section */

.menu-toggle {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 2rem;
  right: 2rem;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 99px;
  background-color: #ed7014;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50% - 2px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 32px;
}

.button>span,
.button>span::before,
.button>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 99px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.button>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}

.button>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}


/* Button Animation */

.menu-toggle.is-active .button>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-toggle.is-active .button>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.menu-toggle.menu-toggle.is-active .button>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}


/* Sidebar Footer */

.white-section {
  text-align: center;
}

.p-white-sec {
  color: #fff;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 7px 15px;
}

.footer-icon {
  margin: 20px 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-icon:hover {
  color: #ffa500;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}


/* Mobile Size */

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  /* Sidebar Section */
  .sidebar {
    max-width: 200px;
  }
  .sidebar img {
    height: 6.5rem;
    width: 10rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /* Sidebar Section */
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -300px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
  }
  .sidebar.is-active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .sidebar img {
    height: 6.5rem;
    width: 10rem;
  }
  /* Content */
  .content {
    padding-top: 8rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Codin'up | HTML Course</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;400;900&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bungee&family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.png">

  <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/List of Course/HTML Course.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="app">
    <!-- Button for Sidebar -->
    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <div class="button">
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Sidebar Section -->
    <aside class="sidebar">
      <a href="/HTML/List of Course/HTML Course.html">
        <img src="/Logo/Codin'up Logo (1) White.png" alt="Codin'up">
      </a>
      <h3>HTML Course</h3>

      <nav class="menu">
        <a href="/HTML/Home.html" class="menu-item">Home</a>
        <a href="/HTML/Courses.html" class="menu-item">Courses</a>
      </nav>

      <hr>

      <nav class="menu">
        <a href="/HTML/List of Course/HTML Course.html" class="menu-item is-active">HTML Introduction</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
      </nav>

      <hr>

      <!-- Sidebar Footer -->
      <footer class="white-section" id="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a href="https://twitter.com/i/flow/login"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter footer-icon"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/login.php/"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f footer-icon"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.secure.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/pbnddj/&source=profile_posts&hl=en-gb"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram footer-icon"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.google.com/gmail/about/"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope footer-icon"></i></a>
          <p class="p-white-sec">&copy; 2022 ITMAWD21 Group 3</p>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </aside>

    <!-- Content Section -->
    <main class="content">
      <h1>Introduction To HTML</h1>
      <img src="/Logo/HTML Logo.png" alt="Codin'up Logo">

      <strong>Description</strong>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium ipsa, quod, placeat cupiditate enim hic natus maiores nobis sequi nisi odit voluptas earum quas perspiciatis qui explicabo recusandae ullam quibusdam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dignissimos obcaecati exercitationem voluptatem accusamus, beatae sunt voluptatibus quam odio magnam, mollitia minima dicta distinctio, amet accusantium! Dolore debitis qui quis iusto. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium harum corrupti nisi ratione aperiam commodi rerum. Delectus illum suscipit distinctio unde iste veritatis voluptate nulla, enim rem harum ullam rerum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Ut cumque totam ipsum, quia voluptate quam esse reprehenderit explicabo atque, molestiae doloribus earum repellendus architecto aperiam minima impedit dicta autem laboriosam! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique,
        corrupti adipisci. Itaque sint, nemo laborum a ratione corrupti laboriosam tenetur soluta pariatur nostrum fuga, earum voluptate ducimus iure ipsum saepe? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi repudiandae recusandae
        iste, molestiae modi ea numquam vero repellat. Doloremque iusto labore nobis placeat perspiciatis optio repellendus eius adipisci voluptas expedita. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor doloremque rem debitis? Sed quod
        eligendi inventore deleniti aliquid velit, magni perferendis, quaerat officiis in consequuntur tenetur ipsum animi tempore asperiores.</p>

      <!-- Sample Code Content -->
      <div class="sample-code">
        <p>&lt;html&gt;</p>
        <p><span style="padding-left: 20px;">&lt;head&gt;</span></p>
        <p><span style="padding-left: 40px;">&lt;title&gt;HTML Course&lt;/title&gt;</span></p>
        <p><span style="padding-left: 20px;">&lt;/head&gt;</span></p>
        <p><span style="padding-left: 20px;">&lt;body&gt;</span></p>
        <p><span style="padding-left: 40px;">&lt;p&gt;Hello World&lt;p&gt;</span></p>
        <p><span style="padding-left: 20px;">&lt;/body&gt;</span></p>
        <p>&lt;/html&gt;</p>
      </div>

      <strong>Code Description</strong>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iusto, eveniet repudiandae ratione sint harum pariatur id numquam doloremque sequi eaque quo accusamus ab nihil aut alias inventore! Cumque, tempore.</p>
    </main>
  </section>

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c9df5e490e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap JS & External JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="/JS/List of Course/HTML Course.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fit the content to the right beside my sidebar, especially its layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just apply `position: sticky` and `height: 100vh` on the sidebar:

```css
position: sticky;
height: 100vh;
```

Giving it `height: 100vh` makes sure the sidebar always stretches to the entire height of the screen. `position: sticky` works in a similiar fashion to `position: fixed` but it doesn't affect the document flow in the same way. You can then apply positioning values such as `top: 0` and `left: 0`, but those properties are already applied in your snippet.

```js
// Not bringing sidebar when active
const menu_toggle = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');

// When the button is clicked the sidebar will be active in the following code
menu_toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menu_toggle.classList.toggle('is-active');
  sidebar.classList.toggle('is-active');
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Sidebar Section */

.app {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(#ed7014, #fa5b3d);
  /* With Scrollbar */
  /* Edit start */
  position: sticky;
  height: 100vh;
  /* Edit end */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}

.sidebar h3 {
  font-family: 'Bungee', cursive;
  color: #fff;
}

.sidebar .menu {
  margin: 0 -1rem;
}

.sidebar .menu .menu-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.sidebar .menu .menu-item:hover,
.sidebar .menu .menu-item.is-active {
  color: rgb(255, 238, 151);
  ;
  border-right: 5px solid rgb(255, 238, 151);
}


/* Content Scrollbar */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffa500;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #d67229;
}


/* Content Section */

.content {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: linear-gradient(#dd5713, #d67229);
}

.content img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.content h1 {
  font-family: 'Bungee', cursive;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.content strong {
  font-family: 'Bungee', cursive;
  color: #fff;
}

.content p {
  text-align: justify;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Sample Code Content */

.sample-code {
  width: 65%;
  background: rgb(255, 238, 151);
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px;
}

.sample-code p {
  color: #000;
}


/* Button Sidebar section */

.menu-toggle {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 2rem;
  right: 2rem;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 99px;
  background-color: #ed7014;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50% - 2px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 32px;
}

.button>span,
.button>span::before,
.button>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 99px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.button>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}

.button>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}


/* Button Animation */

.menu-toggle.is-active .button>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-toggle.is-active .button>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.menu-toggle.menu-toggle.is-active .button>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}


/* Sidebar Footer */

.white-section {
  text-align: center;
}

.p-white-sec {
  color: #fff;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 7px 15px;
}

.footer-icon {
  margin: 20px 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-icon:hover {
  color: #ffa500;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}


/* Mobile Size */

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  /* Sidebar Section */
  .sidebar {
    max-width: 200px;
  }
  .sidebar img {
    height: 6.5rem;
    width: 10rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /* Sidebar Section */
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -300px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
  }
  .sidebar.is-active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .sidebar img {
    height: 6.5rem;
    width: 10rem;
  }
  /* Content */
  .content {
    padding-top: 8rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Codin'up | HTML Course</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;400;900&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bungee&family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.png">

  <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/List of Course/HTML Course.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="app">
    <!-- Button for Sidebar -->
    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <div class="button">
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Sidebar Section -->
    <aside class="sidebar">
      <a href="/HTML/List of Course/HTML Course.html">
        <img src="/Logo/Codin'up Logo (1) White.png" alt="Codin'up">
      </a>
      <h3>HTML Course</h3>

      <nav class="menu">
        <a href="/HTML/Home.html" class="menu-item">Home</a>
        <a href="/HTML/Courses.html" class="menu-item">Courses</a>
      </nav>

      <hr>

      <nav class="menu">
        <a href="/HTML/List of Course/HTML Course.html" class="menu-item is-active">HTML Introduction</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">HTML Course no.</a>
      </nav>

      <hr>

      <!-- Sidebar Footer -->
      <footer class="white-section" id="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a href="https://twitter.com/i/flow/login"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter footer-icon"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/login.php/"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f footer-icon"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.secure.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/pbnddj/&source=profile_posts&hl=en-gb"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram footer-icon"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.google.com/gmail/about/"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope footer-icon"></i></a>
          <p class="p-white-sec">&copy; 2022 ITMAWD21 Group 3</p>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </aside>

    <!-- Content Section -->
    <main class="content">
      <h1>Introduction To HTML</h1>
      <img src="/Logo/HTML Logo.png" alt="Codin'up Logo">

      <strong>Description</strong>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium ipsa, quod, placeat cupiditate enim hic natus maiores nobis sequi nisi odit voluptas earum quas perspiciatis qui explicabo recusandae ullam quibusdam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dignissimos obcaecati exercitationem voluptatem accusamus, beatae sunt voluptatibus quam odio magnam, mollitia minima dicta distinctio, amet accusantium! Dolore debitis qui quis iusto. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium harum corrupti nisi ratione aperiam commodi rerum. Delectus illum suscipit distinctio unde iste veritatis voluptate nulla, enim rem harum ullam rerum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Ut cumque totam ipsum, quia voluptate quam esse reprehenderit explicabo atque, molestiae doloribus earum repellendus architecto aperiam minima impedit dicta autem laboriosam! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique,
        corrupti adipisci. Itaque sint, nemo laborum a ratione corrupti laboriosam tenetur soluta pariatur nostrum fuga, earum voluptate ducimus iure ipsum saepe? Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi repudiandae recusandae
        iste, molestiae modi ea numquam vero repellat. Doloremque iusto labore nobis placeat perspiciatis optio repellendus eius adipisci voluptas expedita. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor doloremque rem debitis? Sed quod
        eligendi inventore deleniti aliquid velit, magni perferendis, quaerat officiis in consequuntur tenetur ipsum animi tempore asperiores.</p>

      <!-- Sample Code Content -->
      <div class="sample-code">
        <p>&lt;html&gt;</p>
        <p><span style="padding-left: 20px;">&lt;head&gt;</span></p>
        <p><span style="padding-left: 40px;">&lt;title&gt;HTML Course&lt;/title&gt;</span></p>
        <p><span style="padding-left: 20px;">&lt;/head&gt;</span></p>
        <p><span style="padding-left: 20px;">&lt;body&gt;</span></p>
        <p><span style="padding-left: 40px;">&lt;p&gt;Hello World&lt;p&gt;</span></p>
        <p><span style="padding-left: 20px;">&lt;/body&gt;</span></p>
        <p>&lt;/html&gt;</p>
      </div>

      <strong>Code Description</strong>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui iusto, eveniet repudiandae ratione sint harum pariatur id numquam doloremque sequi eaque quo accusamus ab nihil aut alias inventore! Cumque, tempore.</p>
    </main>
  </section>

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c9df5e490e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap JS & External JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="/JS/List of Course/HTML Course.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand well, but:

Try to add this in the content class:

```
width: 100%;
padding-left: 300px; /* The width of the menu */
```

Answer (score 0):

`.sidebar` has a `position: fixed;`.

You could apply styling to the main content `<main class="content" style="left: 272px;position: absolute;">`.  But you must also account for the media queries adjusting the width of the sidebar.  E.g.,

```
@media (max-width: 1024px){
  .sidebar {
     max-width: 200px;
  }
  main.content {
     left: 200px;
  }
}
```

and

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -300px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
  }

  main.content {
     left: 0;
     height: 100%;
  }
}
```

I would also use width property over `max-width`. To be sure that the content always aligns as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the layout. Maybe you can try using rows and columns to sort it out:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">
     //Sidebar code
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-xs-8">
     //Content code
    </div>
</div>
```

This could be a better option and will also be responsive.

If you are not comfortable or familiar then maybe, like others suggested, you can remove the `position: fixed` styling in `.sidebar`. It will solve this problem temporarily.